# How to navigate UIWebView when click UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I load the data (Google,Yahoo,Facebook) in `UITableView`, when I click (Google) it should redirect to the Gmail page using `UIWebView`.

What do I write in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view controller that contain WebView and then in TableViewController Add this code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
WebViewController *WebViewController = [[TrackViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];

//And do here code for passing URL to  WebViewController   

[self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:NO];


}
```

And if you are using navigation controller than

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    WebViewController *WebViewController = [[TrackViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];

    //And do here code for passing URL to  WebViewController   

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:aTrackViewController  animated:NO];


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use navigaion controller,Load a webview with specific url on didSelectRowAtIndexpath method getting and passing the selected url from table

Comment: can you please give me some code for that?